# Unexpected index values when chaining filter functions

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

The following code produces the result I desire:

```
// output 1,2,3,4,5,etc
var input$ = Rx.Observable.interval(500).map((v, idx) => idx+1);

var inputEveryOtherOdd$ = input$
  // filter even numbers
  .filter(v => v % 2)
  .map(x => x) // workaround to fix the index (read below)
  // filter every other remaining number (take every other odd number)
  .filter((v, idx) => {
    console.log(`Value: ${v}, Index: ${idx}`)
    return !(idx % 2);
  })
  .subscribe(function(v) {
    output.textContent+= v;
  })
;
```

The log produces:

```
Value: 1, Index: 0
Value: 3, Index: 1
Value: 5, Index: 2
Value: 7, Index: 3
Value: 9, Index: 4
```

Each item that passes the first filter has the next index so that the index is incremented by one for each item `(0,1,2,3,4,5,etc)`.

What I can't understand is if I remove `map`, the second filter receives different `idx` values for the same items:

```
Value: 1, Index: 0
Value: 3, Index: 2
Value: 5, Index: 4
Value: 7, Index: 6
Value: 9, Index: 8
```

It seems that the values filtered in the first filter are still being considered in the second filter. I can't make any sense of it. The filter function doesn't run for the values, so how can the index be incrementing for items that don't exist? Why does `map` make any difference?

[**Click here for live demo.**](http://jsbin.com/quqewugecu/1/edit?html,js,output)

I expect chaining two filters together would produce the same result as synchronous filtering and the `idx` value would be `0,1,2,3,4,5,etc` in each filter.

```
var result = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  .filter(v => v % 2)
  .filter((v, idx) => !(idx % 2));
```

I was originally using `startWith` in place of `map`. It seems like just putting something in between the filters makes the `idx` value what I expect.

Comment: Works as expected in RxJS 5.0. http://jsbin.com/lizupasiju/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is ironically a "feature" of the current version (v4) of RxJS.

The `filter` operator contains an optimization to detect if it is being used in a "chained" manner, that is, if you have multiple filters in a row. If it is then it will not create a second `FilterObservable` but rather will wrap the new filter operation in as part of the existing Observable.

See source code [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/perf/operators/filter.js#L58-L59) and [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/perf/operators/filter.js#L14-L16).

As a result, no matter how many filters you chain together you will *always* receive the same index for all of them.

When you use an operator in between the two filters then it cannot perform the optimization and so the filters will not be merged and you will see different indices.

Comment: Wow. Alrighty then. So is `map` the best way to go? Is there a standard thing people do in this circumstance? Or is chaining filters a sign that I should do this some other way?

Comment: I think that will be your best bet, `map` is fairly efficient so you won't incur much overhead. To be honest, I have never seen this issue before, so I don't know what the standard approach would be. If anything else comes to mind I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The index`idx` is the index of the element in the original list, independently of what has been filtered out.

Comment: That is apparently the case, but I need to know how to get around that and why `startWith` changes the idx.

Comment: I'm guessing that since `startWith` prepends a value to the original sequence, a new "reorganized" sequence is created and the indices are "reordered".

Comment: That might be kinda true, but `map` does the same thing just passing the values through. Just doesn't make sense.